# keras TimeDistributed layer wrap a Lambda layer where has multi different size input

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I write a custom conv function which needs to input the kernel and bias, then using Keras.layers.Lambda to call this function. My problem is that the input x is a 5D tensor while the kernel and bias is not, but I have to use the TimeDistributed layer to wrap this Lambda layer, so how can I do ? E.g.

```py
def my_conv(input_var):
    inputs, input_kernel, input_bias = input_var
    activation = activation.get("sigmod")
    x = K.conv2d(inputs, input_kernel, strides=1)
    x = K.bias_add(x, input_bias)
    return activation(x)
def my_conv_shape(input_shape):
    input_shape, kernel_shape, bias_shape = input_shape
    return input_shape[:3] + bias_shape[-1:]
```

In another function I use it:

```py
def custom_conv(x, kernel, bias):
    """x: [batch_size, max_num, height, width, channel]
       kernel: [size, size, input_dim, filters]
       bias: [filers]
    """    
    x = KL.TimeDistributed(KL.Lambda(my_conv, output_shape=tmy_conv_shape), name="my_conv")([x, kernel, bias])
```

but I think in this way should not work.